# Unable to define desired function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I was reading a python book and I got a question which is:

> Define a new function called "do_four" that takes a function object
>   and a value and calls the function four times, passing the value as a
>   parameter. There should be only two statements in the body of this
>   function, not four.

I tried but now I want that it should print 16 times anything but there should be 2 statement in body of each function. My code is

```
def hello1(a, g):
    a(g)
    a(g)

def hello2(ar):
    print (ar)
    print (ar)

hello1(hello2, "hello")
print("")

def do_four(a, g):
    hello1(a, g)
    hello1(a, g)

do_four(hello2, "hjh")
print("")

def hello3(a, g):
    print (a, g)
    print (a, g)

hello3(do_four, "aad")
```

and I am getting this output:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello

hjh
hjh
hjh
hjh
hjh
hjh
hjh
hjh

<function do_four at 0x1056a9840> aad
<function do_four at 0x1056a9840> aad
```

Can someone explain what I am missing and how I can do this?

P.S. - I don't want to use loop now. I am learning functions.

Comment: "i don't want to use loop now" - well, too bad, because loops are the answer.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that says you can't use a loop, which is the simplest most logical way to solve the problem with only two lines of code in total. While the function in the answer you have selected only contains two lines, they require the addition of whole other function to work — which I think goes against the spirit of the question (as well as the Python language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code :

```
    def hello1(a,g):
    a(g)
    a(g)

def hello2(ar):
    print(ar)
    print(ar)
hello1(hello2, "hello")
print("")

def do_four(a,g):
    hello1(a,g)
    hello1(a,g)

do_four(hello2, "hello1")
print("")


def do_eight(sf):
    print(sf)
    print(sf)
do_four(do_eight, "hello2")

def do_eight1(a,g):
    do_four(a,g)
    do_four(a,g)

do_eight1(do_eight, "hello3")

def do_sixteen(add):
    print(add)
    print(add)

do_eight1(do_sixteen, "hello4")

def do_sixteen1(a,g):
    do_eight1(a,g)
    do_eight1(a,g)

do_sixteen1(do_sixteen, "hello5")
```

Comment: thanks ! actually you spell function name wrong like four will be eight and eight will sixteen but its ok i got answer now :))

Answer (score 7):

What the description calls for is something like this

```
def some_func(arg):
    print(arg)

def do_four(fun, arg):
    for _ in range(0, 4):
        fun(arg)
```

and then it is called like

```
do_four(some_func, "foo")
```

This solution uses a loop.  Not sure why you have an aversion to loops, that is explicitly what is needed given the description

> There should be only two statements in the body of this function, not four.

If you really wanted to do this with no loop (and I really don't understand why) then `do_four` would look like

```
def do_four(fun, arg):
    fun(arg)
    fun(arg)
    fun(arg)
    fun(arg)
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to do this without loops, and want only 2 statements per function then you could do...

```
def do_two(fun, arg);
    fun(arg)
    fun(arg)

def do_four(fun, arg):
    do_two(fun, arg)
    do_two(fun, arg)
```

Comment: i appreciate your help but i want to do this by functions only no loop :)

Comment: @user325923 explain to us why no loop?

Comment: causes i want to understand functions  first . i know how to do this with help of loop but i want to try with functions and only two statement in each body of function .

Comment: what is this can anyone explain please ?

`<function do_four at 0x1056a9840> aad
<function do_four at 0x1056a9840> aad`

Comment: @user325923 what is what?  Do you need explanation of the answer posted?

Comment: You can/should replace `range(0, 4)` with `range(4)`.

Comment: hi i am facing one error can anyone help ??

which is this error `TypeError: hello3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'g'`

and code is

`def hello1(a, g):
    a(g)
    a(g)

def hello2(ar):
    print (ar)
    print (ar)

hello1(hello2, "hela")
print("")

def hello3(a, g):
    print (a, g)
    print (a, g)

hello1(hello3, "hea")`

Comment: Understanding functions means *not* using functions when the problem at hand doesn't apply to them. You aren't going to build an understanding of functions by doing a for-loop exercise in a roundabout manner (what if the assignment had been to write `do_1048576`?)

Answer (score 2):

As user2357112 said, you need to use a loop:

```
def do_four(fun, value):
    for _ in range(4):
        fun(value)
```

edit: without a loop, you could do this hack:

```
def do_four(fun, value):
    [fun(value), fun(value), fun(value), fun(value)]
```

But that is a ***very ugly*** hack. You need to learn how to use loops, not how to write smelly code.

Comment: but there are four statement i think :D

Comment: Ha I was wondering how that counts. One statement with four nested statements?

Answer (score 0):

The question wants you to write a function that can be called like this:

```
do_four( say_hello, "you" )
```

While you are trying to write it the other way around.  You're learning about functions - good!  Understand that functions are things you can pass to other functions, that's the key to solving this problem, and probably what you should take a way from this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
def do_four(fn, arg, n=4):
    if n:
        do_four(fn, arg, n-1) or fn(arg)
```

Or with a 1 line body

```
def do_four(fn, arg, n=4):
    not n or do_four(fn, arg, n-1) or fn(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have only two statements then make it with the modulus:

```
for index in range(4):
    if index%2 == 0:
        print("foo")
```

This gives out:

```
foo
foo
```

So in your case:

```
def some_func(arg):
    print(arg)

def do_four(fun, arg):
    for index in range(0, 4):
        if index%2 == 0:
            fun(arg)
```

Hope this can help. Greetings Chri

**EDIT**
Sry, I didn't answer the question (two Statements in one function)

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion together with optional parameters to avoid loops, but that requires at least 3 statements inside the function:

```py
def do_four (func, arg, repeat=4):
    if repeat > 0:
        func(arg)
        do_four(func, arg, repeat-1)
```